# mysql sort string with dimensions and quotes

Tags: mysql, sorting, alphanumeric

I'm trying to sort a field that has letters, numbers and quotes but I can't get the results in order. A field (named name) in a table has data like this, though not ordered as shown:

```
    6"w x 9"h 
    6"w x 10"h 
    7"w x 8"h 
    7"w x 9"h 
    7"w x 10"h 
    7"w x 21"h 
    10"w x 10"h
```

The command I'm using is

```
    select name from my_table order by name;
```

The result is

```
    10"w x 10"h
    6"w x 10"h
    6"w x 9"h 
    7"w x 10"h
    7"w x 21"h
    7"w x 8"h 
    7"w x 9"h
```

I've tried all of the following that I found on this site. I couldn't get the last one to work at all but the others worked a little better than the above but still not correct.

```
    order by name * 1

    order by name + 0

    order by CAST(name AS DECIMAL(10,2))

    order by length(name), name

    order by  CAST(SUBSTR(name, 0, LOCATE('w', name) - 1) AS int),
    CAST(SUBSTR(name FROM (LOCATE('h', name) - 1)) AS int)
```

The first two alternatives above gave this output so they are almost doing it.

```
    6"w x 9"h 
    6"w x 10"h 
    7"w x 10"h 
    7"w x 21"h 
    7"w x 9"h 
    7"w x 8"h 
    10"w x 10"h
```

Does anyone know how to sort these so they are in proper order, like below.

```
    6"w x 9"h 
    6"w x 10"h 
    7"w x 8"h 
    7"w x 9"h 
    7"w x 10"h 
    7"w x 21"h 
    10"w x 10"h
```

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function to extract both values, and then sort by using them. What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one is in the right direction. You need to order by the number in the string:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(name, 1, LOCATE('"w', name) - 1) AS signed),
    CAST(SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('x', name) + 1, LOCATE('"h', name) - LOCATE('x', name) -1) AS signed)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function to extract complex expressions of variable length:

```
select dimension 
from (
  select
    dimension
    cast(regexp_substr(dimension, '[0-9]+') as int) as w,
    cast(substr(regexp_substr(dimension, 'x +[0-9]+'), 3, 10) as int) as h
  from t
)
order by w, h
```